# Azure resize VM from A2/3 to DS2 v2

Tags: centos, azure

I'm trying to resize a couple of Azure VMs created some time ago from basic A3 and standard A3 to standard DS2v2.

I don't seem to have the ability to resize to that size of VM. It would be a bit of a pain to have to rebuild the servers from scratch.

If it makes any difference I am running CentOS in the VMs, each with a single disk with the apps and OS on it.

Can anyone advise me if it's possible to remove the VM without deleting the disks, create a new VM and then attach the disk to the new VM? I can't seem to find a way of doing it.

Thanks.....

Answer (score 2):

> Can anyone advise me if it's possible to remove the VM without
>   deleting the disks, create a new VM and then attach the disk to the
>   new VM?

Which module are the VMs deploy in? (ARM or ASM)

If your VMs deploy in **ASM**(classic), we can delete your VM and select **keep the attached disks**, and **copy** the VHD to another **storage account(premium)**, then use classic portal to create new VM with **MY DISKS**, after the VM created, select the data disk and attach it:
[image]

If your VMs deploy in **ARM**, we can delete your VM(just VM),**keep the VHD**,and **copy** the VHD to another **storage account(premium)** and use template to create new VMs with VHD. After VMs created, select data disk and attach it.
Here is the [**template**](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/templates/201-vm-os-disk-and-data-disk-existing-vnet/), Create a VM from existing VHDs (OS + data disk) and connect it to an existing VNET.
[image]

**Note:**

We should copy the VHD to a premium storage account, then we can use the VHD to create a new VM.

Comment: We can't use standard storage account to create a DS2v2 size VM, we should copy OS disk to Premium storage account, then use this VHD to create New VM.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the VM will not delete the disks. You can recreate the VMs using PowerShell/CLI or ARM template deployment. Here are the steps:

[Migrating to Azure Premium Storage (Unmanaged Disks)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-migration-to-premium-storage#scenario1)

The reason you can't resize is that DS VMs utilizes a different hardware cluster because of SSD disk support. If you have no intention of using SSD disks, look for the same D-sized VM without the "S" and you won't need to redeploy. If you can't see regular D VMs, then your VM is running in a very old cluster and a redeploy is necessary no matter what.

Comment: Thanks for all the help so far. I don't seem to have an option to remove a VM without destroying the associated root disk. Am I missing a flag somewhere? I'm using the resource manager model (not classic).

Comment: Don't worry. You won't destroy the Os disk. Deleting virtual machines does not delete any of the disks.

Answer (score 0):

VMs of "DS" category use premium storage, while VMs of "A" category use standard storage; you can't move those VMs between different categories, because they are physically stored in different and incompatible places.

You need to delete the existing VMs (which will not delete their disks), copy their disks to a premium storage account, and then create new VMs using the copied disks.